# Populate UITableView Cells from JSON dates

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am having a hard time populating the tableview cells with json feed dates field. I think it has do to with the way I am getting the dates

```
NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in json){
        [datesArray addObject:[tempDict objectForKey:@"date"]];
    }
```

Please assist if you can. I have gone through everything I can think of (still learning).

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AvailabilityViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{

    NSDate *appointmentdate;
    UIActionSheet *dateSheet;
    UITextField *mydatetextfield;
    UILabel *pastDateLabel;
    NSArray *json;

}
//-(IBAction)getDataFromJson:(id)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *mydatetextfield;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *appointmentdate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pastDateLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *_tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *json;
//-(void)setDate;
-(void)dismissDateSet;
-(void)cancelDateSet;



@end
```

.m file

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data

    NSError* error;
    //NSLog(@"string is %@", responseData);

    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"string is %@", responseData);
    if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its an array");
    } else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a dictionary");
    }  else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a string");
    }  else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a number");
    }  else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a null");
    } else if (json == nil){
        NSLog(@"nil");
    }
    //NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"date"]; //2
    NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in json){
        [datesArray addObject:[tempDict objectForKey:@"date"]];
    }

    NSLog(@"this is your datesArray %@", datesArray);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.json.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
     cell.textLabel.text = [[self.json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];

    return cell;
    //[_tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is my NSLog of datesArray

```
2012-08-21 10:09:39.303 GBSB[1409:15b03] this is your datesArray (
    "2012-08-13 12:00:00",
    "2012-08-13 10:00:00",
    "2012-08-13 13:00:00"
```

Here is what the viewDidLoad looks like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: 
                        kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) 
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

    });

}
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data

    NSError* error;
    //NSLog(@"string is %@", responseData);

    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"string is %@", responseData);
    if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its an array");
    } else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a dictionary");
    }  else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a string");
    }  else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a number");
    }  else if ([json isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        NSLog(@"its a null");
    } else if (json == nil){
        NSLog(@"nil");
    }
    //NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"date"]; //2
    NSMutableArray *datesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *tempDict in json){
        [datesArray addObject:[tempDict objectForKey:@"date"]];
    }

    NSLog(@"this is your datesArray %@", datesArray);
    NSLog(@"this is the json %@", self.json);


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a local variable called json in your fetchedData method and putting the parsed response in there.  However, because this is a local variable it ceases to exist once your exit from the method.

Instead, what you should do is to put the parsed response data into your viewController's `json` @property which you declare in the .h file.  To do this, make this change to your `fetchedData:` method:

```
self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can pull out the data like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"]
```

Also your `numberOfRowsInSection:` should return:

```
return self.json.count;
```

EDIT:

More explanation about local variables vs. ivars vs. properties...

When you declare this in your view controller's @interface in the .h file:

```
NSArray *json;
```

you are creating in instance variable (ivar) for your class.  Whenever an instance of your class is instantiated it will have a member variable named `json` that you can access within the methods of your class.

When you declare a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *json;
```

and a matching @synthesize in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize json;
```

the compiler auto generates a setter and getter method for you, so you can then use these methods:

```
NSArray *theArray = [self json]; // getter
[self setJson:newArray];         // setter
```

You can do the same in modern Objective-C using dot notation:

```
NSArray *theArray = self.json; // getter
self.json = newArray;          // setter
```

Your property ends up being backed by an ivar, which is by default named the same of the property and will be autogenerated for you if it doesn't exist.  (You can also specify the name of the backing ivar in the @synthesize statement, and you'll often see people using ivar names that start with an underscore to help keep straight what is the ivar name and what is the property name, but I won't go into that further here)

Your object's properties can be accessed from other classes, whereas your object's ivars cannot.

But back to your question.  In addition to your ivar and property, you have created a local variable, also named `json` in your `fetchedData:` method.  This variable, because you declare it within the body of the method, will only exist until the method finishes, at which time it will be deallocated and the data contained will be lost if not retained elsewhere.  Because you have given your local variable the same name as your ivar, the local variable effective hides the ivar.

Apple does not recommend using ivars directly anyway, but instead doing all access through your class properties (getter and setter methods).  That's why I suggested using `self.json`.  It should also fix your problem, since values saved to your property will persist beyond the execution of the method.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: Can you explain this? viewController's @property which you declare in the .h file. To do this, refer to self.json

Comment: So I would use the nsarray *thearray code in my h file instead of just nsarray *json? I changed to your recommendation and the celltextlabel.text still shows nothing.

Comment: Or just delete the nsarray *json and leave the property one?

Comment: Have you tried making the changes I suggested in my original answer?  I think those changes will solve your problem.

Comment: So what is the exact nature of your problem?  Are you not getting the correct number of cells?  Are the cells showing something incorrect?  Try adding an NSLog statement to `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to confirm that your array is the expected length, and another NSLog statement to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to confirm that method is being called.  Also do an NSLog of your json itself and report back what it looks like.

Comment: When is your `fetchedData` method being called?  If it is being called somewhere other than in `viewDidLoad`, you will need to call [self.tableView reloadData to make the table redraw with the new data.

Comment: I edited above to show the viewDidLoad. the datesArray is the data that I am really after. It seems to be calling in the viewDidLoad. Thanks for all the help, I have a feeling a resolution is near. It seems like the data is still not being called outside the method.

Comment: Ok, I think this might be the final key.  Since you are retrieving your data asynchronously, your table is being drawn before your have any data to show.  You should add `[self.tableView reloadData]` to the end of your `fetchedData` method to tell your tableView to redraw itself, since at that point the data will be available.

Comment: Got this error 2012-08-22 13:54:21.343 GBSB[4714:15b03] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UITableView.m:6061
2012-08-22 13:54:21.344 GBSB[4714:15b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: Well, that's a start.  At least your app is trying to draw table cells now.  If you are using a storyboard, did you remember to set the identifier value on your tableView's prototype cell in the storyboard?  (In your code you used the identifier @"Cell", this needs to match the value in your storyboard)

Comment: I had cell from earlier test. thanks so much. No on to the next step. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 'json' is an array of NSDictionary's.

You can't do this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

(i.e. assign an NSDictionary to a UILabel's text field)

but you could do something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
```

Comment: please note, @jonkroll answer is more thorough, he picked up on a few add'l errors that I missed